# How to confirm that none of our projects have VIEW access (or higher) as the default role?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-security

Is there an easy way to confirm that none of our projects have `VIEW` access (or higher) as the default role?

We want to give a handful of external contractors very limited access to specific datasets, but I'm worried that we have historically set up projects with different access controls; from before contractors were going to be onboarded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; unfortunately general use questions for Foundry are off-topic here. Only questions related to programming/writing code in Foundry (e.g. building your own models) are on-topic.

Comment: I'd guess, depending on how the script is written in the answer below - adding that to the answer might be helpful, both in terms of usefulness and topicality for SO?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a new test user and on the /projects page, filter by  role to see if the fresh user (who you don’t add to any Multipass groups) has any roles.